# versioning different directory name from repository

Tags: windows, git, github

I have a local directory at my/local/directory/ with the files I wish to commit to the repository named differently than 'directory'.  Is it possible to do this and if so how in the command line (windows)?

Comment: do you want one path has two named or linked ? for example you can DOSKEY to make alias in cmd `DOSKEY ls=dir /B`, or make symlink path link `mklink /D C:\TestFolder C:\Users\soheil\test`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read the Git manual first. You can name your directory as you like. The important think is the `.git` folder insight your directory.

If you have no git repository then you should initialize a new one and copy your files to that directory.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1

Comment: Excuse me but I did read the manual and the answer wasn't apparently clear to me and still isn't.  Perhaps I wasn't specific enough: I have an existing web app stored locally and need to figure out how to version it to repository I made on github with a different directory name.